# Matlab - Display two images with original dimensions in the same window

Tags: matlab

I have two grayscale images, I1 of size (w1,h1), and I2 of size (w2,h2). I would like Matlab to display them in the same figure, like this:

```
figure;
subplot(2,1,1), imshow(I1);
subplot(2,1,2), imshow(I2);
```

This code makes the images to be resized in order to be displayed with the same width.

I would like to keep the images in their original sizes (each pixel of each image takes one pixel on the screen). Is there any option I can pass to subplot or imshow to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`truesize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/truesize.html):

```
figure
subplot(2,1,1), imshow(I1)
subplot(2,1,2), imshow(I2)
truesize
```

You will get a warning if it doesn't fit on the screen. Like:

```
Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 66% scale.
```

---

**Edit:** It worked for me because the two images I used had the same size. Apparently the general case doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
figure;
subplot(2,1,1), imshow(I1); axis equal;
subplot(2,1,2), imshow(I2); axis equal;
```

You could also try using `axis image`.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html